# How to bring top a specific textbox

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a userform that contains a lot of objects.I am trying to widen some of the textboxs depending on text lenght and upon exit return textbox to it's original size.My problem is when i change the width,textbox next to it stays on front.I tried to find something on object properties that would help but nothing worked.Thanks for the help beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Z order:

```
Textbox1.ZOrder msoBringToFront
```

for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer.I really appreciate it.